# Pandas - Convert HH:MM:SS.F string to seconds - Caveat : HH sometimes goes over 24H

Tags: date, datetime, pandas, seconds

I have the following dataframe :

> `**flashtalking_df =**`

```
+--------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| Placement ID | Average Interaction Time | Total Interaction Time |
+--------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|      2041083 | 00:01:04.12182           | 24:29:27.500           |
|      2041083 | 00:00:54.75043           | 52:31:48.89108         |
+--------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

where 00:01:04.12182 = HH:MM:SS.F

I need to convert both columns, Average Interaction Time, and Total Interaction Time into seconds.

The problem is that Total Interaction Time goes over 24h.

I found the following code which works for the most part. However, when the Total Interaction Time goes over 24h, it gives me

`ValueError: time data '24:29:27.500' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'`

This is the function I am currently using, which I grabbed from another Stack Overflow question, for both Average Interaction Time and Total Interaction Time:

```
flashtalking_df['time'] = flashtalking_df['Total Interaction Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%H:%M:%S.%f'))
flashtalking_df['timedelta'] = flashtalking_df['time'] - datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00:00.00000','%H:%M:%S.%f')
flashtalking_df['Total Interaction Time'] = flashtalking_df['timedelta'].apply(lambda x: x / np.timedelta64(1, 's'))
```

If there's an easier way, please let me know.

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need first convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then to `seconds` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Average Interaction Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Average Interaction Time'])
                                   .astype('timedelta64[s]')
                                   .astype(int)

df['Total Interaction Time'] =   pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Interaction Time'])
                                   .astype('timedelta64[s]')
                                   .astype(int)
                                   .map('{:,.2f}'.format)
print (df)
   Placement ID  Average Interaction Time Total Interaction Time
0       2041083                        64              88,167.00
1       2041083                        54             189,108.00
```

Solution with [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), thank you [NickilMaveli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485246/pandas-convert-hhmmss-f-string-to-seconds-caveat-hh-sometimes-goes-over/40485568?noredirect=1#comment68216435_40485568):

```
df['Average Interaction Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Average Interaction Time'])
                                   .dt.total_seconds()
                                   .map('{:,.2f}'.format)
df['Total Interaction Time'] =   pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Interaction Time'])
                                   .dt.total_seconds()
                                   .map('{:,.2f}'.format)

print (df)   
   Placement ID Average Interaction Time Total Interaction Time
0       2041083                    64.12              88,167.50
1       2041083                    54.75             189,108.89
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael! Thanks for the help. Is there any way to add a decimal breakdown as well (eg. 88167 becomes  88,167.50)

Comment: Thank you so much jezreal! On a sidenote. Would you reccomend any course or resource that I can take or reference when I encounter this type of stops so that I can resolve them myself?

Comment: Hi jezrael, one last thing. The conversion doesn't seem to work even with the .map('{:,.2f}'.format

If we take 00:01:04.12182 the result should be 64.12, but the output is still 64

Comment: Hard question - maybe `pandas` docs is very [nice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html). And course unfortunately  I have no idea.

Comment: Do you use python `2` or `python 3` ?

Comment: Hey, I use Python 3

Comment: Interesting, for me it works nice with `pandas 0.19.1`, check you version by `print (pd.show_info())`

Comment: @jezrael, Looks like the OP wants to obtain the entire precision of decimal digits going by the responses - Something like `pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Interaction Time']).apply(lambda td: td.total_seconds())` would suffice.

Comment: @NickilMaveli - thank you, i add it to answer (little modified)